# Using python code within script tag of Jinja Template

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

I am trying to get information from my init.py file and include it in my jinja template. I'm passing the information into my jinja template and have included a script tag inside of my HTML because I need to iterate over some information and get it to appear within the JS. However, things do not seem to be working as expected. Here is my code:

```
var geojson = {
          type: 'FeatureCollection',
          features: [
            {% for place in location_coordinates %}
              {

              }
            {% endfor %}
              ]
    };
```

Within the features list, I would like to create a new object for each item within the location_coordinates variable. However, Visual Studio Code keeps highlighting the code with red to indicate that there is an issue with my code.